# How can I set the option values of my custom list formfield

Tags: form-fields-types

I have created a custom form field which extends the list form field.

I takes some JSON and creates the form options.  I used this documentation: https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

I see here that I can use `getValues` too, but I really want to `setValues`.

Updated, working code:

```
public function getOptions()
{
    $json = '{"items":[{"aliases":["http://www.stackoverflow.com","http://facebook.stackoverflow.com"],"api_site_parameter":"meta.stackoverflow"~}';
    $sites = json_decode($json, true);

    $i = 0;
    foreach($sites['items'] as $site)
    {
        $site = $site['api_site_parameter'];
        $stackExchangesSitesOptions[] = array("value" => $site, "text" => $site);
        $i++;
    }
    // Merge any additional options in the XML definition.
    $options = array_merge(parent::getOptions(), $stackExchangesSitesOptions);
    return $options;
}
```

Comment: Code Review: https://3v4l.org/mc84g ...wow, that documentation page needs some TLC.

Comment: I just updated the documentation page with the learning I just received.

Comment: ...but you didn't include any of my pieces of advice ...or the change isn't published yet?

Comment: Good catch on the '$i', I was using it but no longer needed it.  I tried with just text but the option values were 1, 2, 3

Comment: @mickmackusa I have updated it now :)  It's still useful as an example in case you DO want different options and text values.

Comment: So `value` is required, okay.  Yes, that's true.  From a tutorial/ general-use perspective it is a good idea.

Comment: I have updated the docs to change the value / text because that makes it clearer.  Thanks for your help.  See you on Tuesday :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're extending the list form field `JFormFieldList` then you should provide the function `getOptions()` which should return the list of options for the select field.

The list of options which you return should be an associative array of name/value pairs like this:

```
array(array('value' => 1, 'text' => 'option one'),
      array('value' => 2, 'text' => 'option two'),
      array('value' => 3, 'text' => 'option three'),
      );
```

You will then get the 'value' selected in your http post request from the form.

You can preselect one or more of these values by setting the class protected variable `$this->value`, but note that to set more than 1 you need to have defined `multiple="true"` in the XML definition of your form.

See the sample code for City.php in the Sample Component Code section on https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_custom_form_field_type

Just for information, `getValue()` would be used if you had a custom field which extended `JFormField`. In that case you'd need to provide 3 functions:

1. getLabel() which would provide the label for the field
2. getInput() which would provide the html for the input element
3. getValue() which would provide the value="xxx" attribute for the html input element, and which would then be shown as the value in the input field.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was trying to follow that but I hadn't realised you could use this array to do the list.  If you can help me to resolve it I will update the docs with further information.  I've updated my question with new code.  Can you see what my problem is?

Comment: I think you need to initialise your variable as an empty array at the start, as in: $stackExchangesSitesOptions = array(); before the loop. Does that work?

Comment: The backend actually works now.  I see the values and the name the way I want them and all list options arrive.  So that part is correct.  But the front end if I echo the formfield I just get the word value.  If I do a `var_dump` I get `string(5) "value"`

Comment: It sounds as if it's maybe not picking up your form field code. In your frontend XML file for the form you might have to add an addfieldpath="..."  attribute to point to the folder where you have the custom form field php code.

Comment: It was previously picking it up, but it was spitting out 1, 2, 3 as the values.  I've added `addfieldpath` on my `<fieldset>` already, it wasn't loading in the backend prior to that.

Comment: Ah ha I had to resave my module :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [setValue](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Form.Form.html#method_setValue) method on the form, example:

```
 $this->form->setValue('name', 'group', 'value');
```

Comment: Neat, I think for my list formfield I would need to do a foreach to use this method?  Or is this only for text inputs?

Comment: Not restricted to text inputs. In your view.html.php, within the display() function, you would typically get the form like `$this->form    = $this->get('Form');` then use whatever logic you require e.g. `if($this->form->getValue() === "perhapsadefaultvalue") { $this->form->setValue('yourfieldname', 'group', 'value')`. This probably ought to be done within the `getForm()` of your model however. To answer your question, for a list formfield, you can use `$listfieldvalues[] = $this->form->getValue('yourlistfield')` then loop through that array to setValue.